# In Python3 does num+=roman[s[i:i+2]] not throw key error in loop?

Tags: python

I’m trying to understand a function in Python meant to convert Roman numerals to integers. In the following code:

```
roman = {'I':1,'V':5,'X':10,'L':50,'C':100,'D':500,'M':1000,'IV':4,'IX':9,'XL':40,'XC':90,'CD':400,'CM':900}
s = "III"
i = 0
num = 0
while i < len(s):
    if i+1<len(s) and s[i:i+2] in roman:
        num+=roman[s[i:i+2]]
        i+=2
    else:
        #print(i)
        num
        num+=roman[s[i]]
        i+=1
print(num)
```

The if statement somehow gives an answer of 2, but when I think it through it looks like it should only loop through the if statement once and give 1. But when I think it through further and isolate this section I get a key error ‘II’ which makes sense. So how is the loop not throwing this error and giving a value of 2?

Comment: `s[i:i+2] in roman` is the key check here. Note that it it's false for i = 0.

Comment: @SuperStormer ah okay that makes sense. Is this also what’s causing the value to be equal to 2 in the if statement?

Comment: What value is equal to 2 in the `if` statement?

Comment: @Barmar it was my misunderstanding of how the loop operated. You explained it perfectly below and it all makes sense.

Comment: Besides the above posts pointing the `syntax` error.  The logic prob. not going to work out too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time through the loop, `i = 0` and `s[i:i+2] = 'II'`. `'II' in roman` is not true, so we go to the `else:` block. `s[i] = 'I'`, and `roman['I'] = 1`, so we add 1 to `num`, which now equals `1`. We also add `1` to `i`.

The second time through the loop, `i = 1` and `s[i:i+2] = 'II'`. Again, that's not a key in the dictionary, so we go to the `else:` block and add `roman['I']` to `num`. So now `num = 2`. We also add `1` to `i`.

The third time through the loop, `i = 2` and `i+1 < len(s)` is false. So we go to the `else:` block. `s[i] = 'I'` again, so we we add `1` to `num` again. Now `num = 3`. We also add `1` to `i`.

Now `i = 3` and the condition `while i < len(s):` is no longer true, so the loop ends.

We never get a key error because we always check whether `II` is a key in the dictionary before trying to access `roman['II']`.